# Why in online games do cards belonging to players sat out remain live until a response to a bet or raise is required

Tags: online, tournament

Surely as a replication of live play if the player is not at the table cards should be dead when first card dealt.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is hard to say if player is sitting out or not while playing on-line.

Usually (i.e. at pokerstars) after 1st missed action player is put into state "Sitting out" when it is not dealt any cards until he comes back (hit appropriate button).